# want to change the color of a box with multi color boxes

Tags: html, css

I want to make a code that is showing a big box in right and some Multi small boxes of colours under the big box. when I click the on the small box the big box change its colour and then if I click the next coloured small box the big box change the specific colour. can any one show me direction....Thanks

Comment: Did you somehow forget to show your code so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you can do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/aDQ7M/

HTML:

```
<div id="bigBox"></div>
<div id="multiBoxes">
    <div class="colorPickBox" style="background-color:blue;"></div>
    <div class="colorPickBox" style="background-color:red;"></div>
    <div class="colorPickBox" style="background-color:yellow;"></div>
    <div class="colorPickBox" style="background-color:green;"></div>
    <div class="colorPickBox" style="background-color:brown;"></div>
    <div class="colorPickBox" style="background-color:violet;"></div>
    <div class="colorPickBox" style="background-color:magenta;"></div>
    <div class="colorPickBox" style="background-color:black;"></div>
    <div class="colorPickBox" style="background-color:gray;"></div>
    <div class="colorPickBox" style="background-color:white;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bigBox {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}

.colorPickBox {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".colorPickBox").click(function(){
    $("#bigBox").css("background-color",$(this).css("background-color"));
});
```

And of course insted of using CSS color names (blue, red, green ...), you can use the `rgb()` optinon:

```
background-color:rgb(0,0,255);
```

---

**UPDATE:** Also, if you want to avoid using jQuery, you can do it as easly:

http://jsfiddle.net/PPDfR/

Answer (score 0):

Allthough the js solution is probably the one I would use in real live, you could go for a pure css / html solution. You could use `radio` inputs to store the state, and with some clever use of the `:checked`, `+` and `~` selector. It does require some rather strict html though. Something like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class='options'>
    <input type='radio' name='color' id='color-red'/>
    <label for='color-red'></label>
    <input type='radio' name='color' id='color-green'/>
    <label for='color-green'></label>
    ...
    <div class='selected-color'></div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
/* make the wrapper the reference for the .selected-color
   box and add some padding on top to position that box into */
.options {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 100px;
}
/* turn the labels for the radio's into boxes */
.options label {
    display: inline-block;
    width:20px;
    height: 20px;   
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    margin: 3px;
}
/* give each box a color based on the id of 
   the input it belongs to */
#color-red + label { background: red; }
#color-green + label { background: green; }
...

/* give a border to the hovered / selected color */
input:checked + label, label:hover { border-color: cyan;}

/* hide the actual radio, we only need it to store the state */
input { display:none; }

/* position the .selected color and give it some dimensions */
.selected-color {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
/* give the .selected-color based on the checked radio that precedes it */
#color-red:checked ~ .selected-color { background: red; }
#color-green:checked ~ .selected-color { background: green; }
...
```

And an example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/337uS/

As I said, the html is rather strict. You have to place the input before each label for the `+` selector to work, and the 'big box' has to come after all the inputs and needs to be a sibling for the `~` selector to work. Also the css would grow considerably as the number of options increases, so it is hardly a dynamic solution. But it is feasible, so as a proof of concept...